# Getting a normal ptr from boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, shared-ptr

I have something like `boost::shared_ptr<Type> t(makeSomething(), mem_fun(&Type::deleteMe))`
I now need to call C styled function that requires a pointer to `Type`. How do I get it from `boost::shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 161):

Use the [`get()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#get) method:

```
boost::shared_ptr<foo> foo_ptr(new foo());
foo *raw_foo = foo_ptr.get();
c_library_function(raw_foo);
```

Make sure that your `shared_ptr` doesn't go out of scope before the library function is done with it -- otherwise badness could result, since the library may try to do something with the pointer after it's been deleted.  Be especially careful if the library function maintains a copy of the raw pointer after it returns.

Comment: you should perhaps note something about the shared_ptr going out of scope before the c_library_function has done its thing with the raw_foo.

Comment: roe: i know about that, i just needed to know about get :).

Thanks Adam! :D

Comment: Hi @Adam Rosenfield  , could you explain what happens in a scenario where an exception occurs inside `c_library_function`. That means that the raw_foo is left dangled? or does foo_ptr go ahead and delete the raw_foo, since raw_foo is held by foo_ptr?

Answer (score 37):

Another way to do it would be to use a combination of the `&` and `*` operators:

```
boost::shared_ptr<foo> foo_ptr(new foo());
c_library_function( &*foo_ptr);
```

While personally I'd prefer to use the `get()` method (it's really the right answer), one advantage that this has is that it can be used with other classes that overload `operator*` (pointer dereference), but do not provide a `get()` method.  Might be useful in generic class template, for example.

Comment: I liked your answer just slightly more then Adams, sorry adam.

Comment: @acidzombie24 - I'm not sure why you like this better.  The Get() method is better to use in probably 99% or more of the cases.

Comment: i'm using get but i still like this answer. mostly bc it recommends both what to do and NOT to do.

Comment: That approach will trigger asserts for NULL pointers.  Not good.

Comment: @DrewDormann made a good point here, acidzombie24. You're gonna have problems with null pointers.

Comment: In modern C++, `&*` now falls into the dreaded category of "Undefined Behavior," and is no longer equivalent to `.get()`. `.get()` will correctly handle `nullptr`, as @DrewDormann noted, but even if `&*` doesn't trigger an assert, your compiler _may_ treat it as though it can _never be null_. In particular, `if (&*x == nullptr)` _will not_ produce the same behavior as `if (x.get() == nullptr)` on many modern compilers, which will treat the former as _always false_!

Answer (score 1):

For std::shared_ptr (C++11 onwards) also, there is a get method to obtain the raw pointer. [link](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/get)