# Cast an iterator of a vector of shared_ptr type

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, shared-ptr

How can I cast an iterator of a vector of shared_ptr type? Consider following example:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr < MyClass > type_myClass;

vector< type_myClass > vect;
vector< type_myClass >::iterator itr = vect.begin();

while(itr != vect.end())
{
   //Following statement works, but I wish to rather cast this 
   //to MyClass and then call a function?
   (*itr)->doSomething(); 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting a normal ptr from shared_ptr ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505143/getting-a-normal-ptr-from-shared-ptr)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not want to *cast*, but rather extract a reference to the object:

```
MyClass & obj = *(*it); // dereference iterator, dereference pointer
obj.doSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks. In case if I want to access it using shared_ptr, then is following statement correct? It don't give any compiler error though but I am not sure if thats good. type_myClass aClass = ((type_myClass)(*itr));

Comment: @Vijayendra: Avoid casts whenever you can, and more so C-style casts. The cast in the expression is unneeded, and you might as well say: `type_myClass x = *itr;`. Adding the unnecessary cast means that if at a later time the type in the container or the receiving type change, the compiler will not be able to warn you of the change, and you might be creating bugs in the code.

Comment: Right, thats very fair point. Thanks again for the comments David.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply grab a reference by de-referencing it again.

```
MyClass& ref = **itr;
```

And then cast it or whatever however you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `get()`, [according to the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#get):

```
T * get() const; // never throws
Returns: the stored pointer.
```

It means you can do:

```
type_myClass* ptr =  *itr.get();    
ptr->doSomething();
```