# shared_ptr for a raw pointer argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers, smart-pointers

When the function requires a char*, can you pass in a shared_ptr?

I'm reading in a whole text file (length = 100), and want to store the char's into a char[] array. The naive way I used was this:

```
ifstream dictFile(fileName);
size_t fileLength = 100;
char* readInBuffer(new char[fileLength]);
dictFile.read(readInBuffer, fileLength);
//processing readInBuffuer..............
delete[] readInBuffer;
dictFile.close();
```

Of course there is memory leak if an exception is thrown before  the delete[] statement. I'm wondering if I can use 
shared_ptr readInBuffer(new char[fileLength]);
But the function prototype

> read ( char* s, streamsize n )

won't accept a smart pointer as input? Any tricks?

Edit: I'm trying to write something like this:

```
shared_ptr<char[]> readInBuffer(new char[fileLength]);
dictFile.read(readInBuffer.get(), fileLength);
```

But it won't compile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting a normal ptr from shared\_ptr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505143/getting-a-normal-ptr-from-shared-ptr)

Comment: You already have part of the answer in your question - a regular pointer doesn't have a `get()` method, but a smart pointer does and it does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: A `shared_ptr` isn't smart enough to manage an array. A `unique_ptr`, however, is, if you give it a custom deleter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**BIG FAT WARNING**: creating a `std::shared_ptr<char>` that points to an array provokes undefined behaviour, because the smart pointer will `delete` the pointer, not `delete[]` it. Use a `std::shared_ptr<char[]>` instead!

Leaving this here because it might serve as a useful warning. Original answer follows...

The `get()` function returns the underlying raw pointer. You already wrote this in your code!

```
shared_ptr<char[]> readInBuffer(new char[fileLength]);
dictFile.read(readInBuffer.get(), fileLength);
```

The same result can be achieved with `&*readInBuffer`.

Of course, you have to be certain that `dictFile.read()` doesn't `delete` the pointer, or demons might fly out of your nose.

Comment: Without a custom deleter, `unique_ptr` will simply call `delete p` on the stored pointer. Since the memory was allocated with array new, this produces undefined behavior.

Comment: Ouch, yes, you're right. I'll leave this here and add a big fat warning.

Comment: Ouch, back. `<g>` My comment ended up talking about `unique_ptr` when I meant `shared_ptr`. `shared_ptr` simply doesn't deal with arrays; there are no custom deleters for `shared_ptr`. `unique_ptr` can be used here, though.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using a pointer, you can use a vector instead.

```
std::vector<char> readInBuffer(fileLength);
dictFile.read(&readInBuffer[0], fileLength);
```

Comment: The vector<char> trick is good... So, when the API requires a raw pointer, there's no way to pass in a smart ptr?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't pass a `shared_ptr`. But you can create one, and call its `get()` member function to get a copy of the raw pointer to pass to the function. However, a `shared_ptr` doesn't deal with arrays; that's what `vector` is for. But you can  use a `unique_ptr` to an array to manage that object:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[], std::default_delete<char[]> ptr(new char[whatever]);
f(ptr.get());
```

There may be a shorter way to write that first line, but I don't have time to dig it out.