# Using shared_ptr in C interfaces?

Tags: c++, c, shared-ptr

I have a C library that I'm porting to C++ that makes heavy use of manually reference-counted structs. I've considered using `shared_ptr` to automatically handle the reference counting, but I also want to maintain the C API. The old signatures look something like this:

```
Object* object_create(void);
Object* object_retain(Object* o);
void object_release(Object* o);
```

If I use `shared_ptr`, is there any way to effectively expose this manual reference counting in a C API?

Comment: Just to clarify; you want a shared_ptr to wrap a raw pointer obtained from `object_create`, and have it call `object_release` at the relevant time?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No, I'm reimplenting `Object` as a class (instead of a struct) in C++, and I'm using `shared_ptr` within the C++ code. I'm interested if it's possible to get a raw pointer from a shared_ptr and then somehow still make it work with shared_ptr's refcount.

Comment: You might be better off using [Boost.intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html).

Comment: Ah ok.  Well you can get a raw pointer from a shared_ptr no problem, (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505143/getting-a-normal-ptr-from-shared-ptr), but as you might expect, there is nothing tracking where that raw pointer goes (it's completely outside the reference-counting mechanism at that point).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Understandable, but I guess I'm wondering if there's *any* way of modifying shared_ptr's internal reference count so I can just manually reference count from the C side.

Comment: You can make shared_ptr use a custom deleter.

Comment: For *any* way you can use static list of `shared_ptr`s hold by C code.

Comment: Implementing as a struct in c and class in c++? This way less great pain.

Comment: std::enable_shared_from_this might work for you, but unfortunately you need to have at least one shared_ptr reference from C++ code: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428023/enable-shared-from-this-c0x-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with `shared_ptr`, as you'll have figured out already, is that you can't modify the reference count except by constructing or destroying instances. So no, there's no way to get this to work except by keeping a `shared_ptr` to every constructed `Object` around until its reference count drops to zero, but doing that right entails redoing much of the reference counting, so you gain very little.

Perhaps [`boost::intrusive_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::shared_ptr::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) to retrieve the value of your pointer in your `object_create`.

I'm not sure that you should maintain `object_retain` or `object_release` as it is already automatically handled by the `shared_ptr`.

Do you want your library to be used by C code? If so then as @Angew pointed out in his comment, have a look at Boost.intrusive_ptr, it seems to be the best choice.

If you can assume that client code written in C will use the C library (which I think kind of make sense), then you can completely drop these functions and handle all internally. You can provide a raw pointer for compatibility with C api if you need to but all the lifetime management could be handled automatically with `shared_ptr`.

Comment: The reference count is not maintained automatically on the C side. If the last `shared_ptr` to an `Object` is destroyed but there's still an `Object*` pointing to it, the object is destroyed and the C pointer is left dangling.

Comment: True, I was thinking of a raw pointer used as a viewer of the object, assuming that the `shared_ptr` would handle the lifetime of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no RAII in C you will need to manage the shared pointers yourself via the create/destroy functions. So the handles you return should be shared_ptr-s, and your API would look like this:

```
// Opaque pointer wrapped in structure for type safety (in header)
typedef struct 
{
    void *ptr;
} ObjectHandle;

// Hide the gory details of resolving the shared ptr.
static std::shared_ptr<Object>* resolveHandle(ObjectHandle objectHandle)
{
    return static_cast<std::shared_ptr<Object>*>(objectHandle.ptr);
}

// Just a sample on how to fully resolve the object for internal use.
static Object* resolveObject(ObjectHandle objectHandle)
{
    return resolveHandle(objectHandle)->get();
}

// Public API functions.

ObjectHandle object_create(void)
{
    return ObjectHandle{new std::shared_ptr<Object>(new Object())};
}

ObjectHandle object_retain(ObjectHandle o)
{
    return ObjectHandle{new std::shared_ptr<Object>(*resolveHandle(o))};
}

void object_release(ObjectHandle o)
{
    delete resolveHandle(o);
}
```